# Training set for alphabetic characters

Tags: python, svm, knn, training-data

I am training a kNN model that will recognize alphabetic characters in the range [A-Z0-9].

Most of the training sets that I found online only contain digits [0-9].

Can someone tell me where I can found such training set ([A-Z0-9])?

Comment: [Here](https://www.nist.gov/srd/nist-special-database-19) there is NIST19. If you know how to use it...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry @Vinny I did update the question